# Media cannot play in Google Assistant anymore?

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have an app that will play a blind test: the user has to guess 3 times the music that is played. The app will fetch each music on my server and play them.
In the simulator, everything works fine but when I launch my app frop Google Assistant on my smartphone, I have the error "AUDIO_NOT_PLAYABLE".

My server returns this kind of link: `https://<ip_address>/10sMusic0.mp3`.

The format is correct as it's mp3. The protocol used is HTTPS so this should be good BUT I use a **self-signed certificate** for my server maybe this is the cause.

What can I do to make it work ?

JSON from the starting intent (hello):

```
  "payload": {
      "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Bonjour et Bienvenue sur my App.\n Essayer de deviner l'artiste pour les 3 musiques suivantes",
                "displayText": "Bienvenue sur my_app.\n Essayer de deviner l'artiste pour les 3 musiques suivantes:"
              }
            },
            {
              "mediaResponse": {
                "mediaType": "AUDIO",
                "mediaObjects": [
                  {
                    "contentUrl": "https://<ip_address>/10sMusic0.mp3",
                    "description": "Quel est l'artiste ?",
                    "icon": {
                      "url": "https://cibul.s3.amazonaws.com/event_blind-test-series_291687.jpg"
                    },
                    "name": "Musique à deviner"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "Not yet implemented"
            }
          ]
        },
        "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
      }
    },
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "...",
        "lifespanCount": 99,
        "parameters": {
          "data": "{\"count\":0,\"score\":0,\"finished\":false,\"artist\":\"disturbed\",\"track\":\"down with the sickness\"}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

And this is (a part of) what I get with actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS:

```
"queryResult": {
    "queryText": "actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "..."
      },
      {
        "name": "...",
        "lifespanCount": 98,
        "parameters": {
          "data": "{\"count\":0,\"score\":0,\"finished\":false,\"artist\":\"disturbed\",\"track\":\"down with the sickness\"}"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "..."
      },
      {
        "name": "..",
        "parameters": {
          "MEDIA_STATUS": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.MediaStatus",
            "failureReason": "AUDIO_NOT_PLAYABLE",
            "status": "FAILED"
          }
        }
      },
      [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created a certificate with Let's Encrypt for my website and now the audio is playing also on the Google Home.

Therefore the problem came with my website when it was using self signed certificate for HTTPS.